# Editorconfig class naming conventions and casing - allow any

Tags: c#, editorconfig

Is it possible to allow `editorconfig` to be laxer around class name conventions?

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules#naming-style-properties)

> You must specify a capitalization style as part of your naming style, otherwise your naming style might be ignored.

I really want to allow different naming conventions in my test files.  So I came up with the following:

```
dotnet_naming_symbols.class_group.applicable_kinds = class
dotnet_naming_style.class_underscore_tolerant.capitalization = TAKE_YOUR_PICK
dotnet_naming_style.class_underscore_tolerant.word_separator = _

dotnet_naming_rule.class_rule.symbols = class_group
dotnet_naming_rule.class_rule.style = class_underscore_tolerant
dotnet_naming_rule.class_rule.severity = warning
```

The possible values for capitalization are `pascal_case`, `camel_case`, `first_word_upper`, `all_upper`, `all_lower`.

I was hoping to allow names such as `Foo_spec` and `foo_setup` in the same files.  My scenario is where I have nested classes, so something like the following is acceptable:

```cs
public class Foo_spec
{
    public class A_Foo
    {
        public class named_Bob
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

I don't want to remove the rule - because at least in `Rider` it falls back to the IDE suggestions.